# Matlab: TCP Connection Fread data Size Warning Error

Tags: matlab, warnings, fread

I have a TCP server in my Matlab code, my client sends some data (max 4 bytes) on some triggers from another application to Matlab. I am receiving those numbers but I am also receiving this warning message many times:

**Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period. 'tcpip' unable to read all requested data. For more information on possible reasons, see TCPIP Read Warnings.**

```
clc;
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 55000,'InputBufferSize', 1024,'NetworkRole','Server', 'TimeOut', 0.5);
fopen(t);
while(1)    
    data = fread(t, 4, 'char');    
    dataChar = char(data);
    dataDouble = str2double(dataChar);  
      if (~isnan(dataDouble))
          if (dataDouble == 0)
              fclose(t); % closing the tcp connecting
              error('0 value is received!') % to jump out of Matlab run mode
          else
              disp("Last Receieved double was: " + dataDouble)
          end       
      end       
  end
```

I also tried get(obj1,'BytesAvailable'), but it gives me error. Does anyone know how to bypass this warning?

Comment: data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable, 'char');  -> Compiler says, it must be greater than 0. 
Causing Pause(1) before fread call also did not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read data from the tcpip object while there is non to be read (i.e. the buffer is already empty). Matlab will wait for a while to see if anything comes, then issue a warning.
The normal way to work with tcpip obj is execute a callback on a certain event, and use this callback to read data from the buffer.

There are two modes: either trigger the buffer when a certain terminator is found (e.g. a line feed, if reading text) or when a certain number of bytes have been received.

Assuming all messages have a byte length 4, the syntax would be:

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 55000,'InputBufferSize', 1024,'NetworkRole','Server', 'TimeOut', 0.5);
t.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 4;     % n=4
t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte'; %Read after n bytes have been received
t.BytesAvailableFcn     = @myTcpipCallback;
fopen(t);
```

The callback will be called each time 4 bytes have been received. The callback function syntax would be:

```
function myTcpipCallback(obj,evt)
    data=fread(obj,4,'char'); %Read 4 characters
    % ... do something with data ... %
    if bad_data_received==true
         fclose(obj);
    end
end
```

The while loop is not necessary, it is already handled internally by the tcpip object. The syntax of the callback function follows the Matlab standard `callbackFunction(obj,evt)` where obj is the object from where the event triggering the callback comes (here a `tcpip` object, but graphic objects work the same) and `evt` a structure containing data about the event (e.g. IP/port from where the message comes; for a KeyPress event that would be the key and modifiers).

You write that the client on another application will sent maximum 4 bytes. It is really more convenient to have a fixed the number of bytes (this can be achieved by padding messages on the client side) or some terminator should mark the end if the massages.

Working with a terminator (assuming for instance each message ends up with a line feed), the syntax would be:

```
t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';
t.Terminator = char(10);     % or newline or recent versions of Matlab
```

and the callback

```
function myTcpipCallback(obj,evt)
    data=[obj.UserData ; fread(obj,obj.BytesAvailable,'char')]; %Read all available characters
    %Just in case, check that we have not received more than one message
    term=[0;find(data==obj.Terminator)];
    for ii=1:length(term)-1
       msg=data(term(ii)+1:term(ii+1));
       %Do something with msg%
    end
    obj.UserData=data(term(ii)+1:end);
end
```

If the client sends data fast, some extra data could have been bufferized while the callback function was waiting in the queue, so by the time it is executed, there could be several messages available. The code should take that possibility into account. Unfortunately, the number of bytes available in the buffer when the callback has been triggered is not in the event data.

Finally, if you intend to receive messages of arbitrary length with complex rules to determine if it is complete or not, another possibility is to read bytes one by one and have your own a buffer somewhere, e.g. in the object userdata.

```
t.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 1;     % n=1
t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte'; %Read after n bytes have been received
```

and the callback:

```
function myTcpipCallback(obj,evt)
    % Bufferize
    obj.UserData=[obj.UserData ; fread(obj,1,'char')]; %Read 1 byte

    % Check if the message if known
    msg = obj.UserData;
    if isComplete(msg)  % 
         obj.UserData=[]; % empty buffer
         processMessage(msg); % do something with message
    end
end
```